# menuitem - setActionView() takes up the whole action bar

Tags: android

I have a custom view that I would like to show as an action button. The menu item is defined as:

```
 <item 
    android:id="@+id/myBtn"
    android:icon="@drawable/myicon"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

In my onCreateOptionsMenu(), I inflate the toolbar and obtain my menuitem:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(...);
CustomView view = new CustomView(ctx);
ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(32, 32);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
item.setActionView(view);
```

I do see my custom view being drawn. However, it takes up pretty much the whole width of the action bar. It seems to ignore my layout param settings.

I am wondering if someone can help me fix this problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked:

It appears LayoutParams has no effect on a MenuItem. However, as CustomView is in our control, you can override onMeasure() on CustomView and return an appropriate size.